# Casperjs doesn't execute javascript code

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, slimerjs

I have a page, and I'm referencing a bunch of scripts with regular script tag in the page's header: jQuery, etc, and my compiled script called index.js. Well the latter is big one, around 1.2M (don't ask why).

My index.html seems like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cool</title>
<script src='jQuery.js'></script>
<!-- more scripts -->
<script src='index.js'></script>
<!-- more stuff -->
```

The problem is if I use PhantomJS engine, my script doesn't get executed on any platforms. If I use SlimerJS/XUL then it gets executed on Windows, but doesn't get on OSX. I'm verifying it with a regular waitFor, evaluating a global variable's value, nothing extraordinary:

```
casper.test.begin('index.js executes', 1, function (test) {
    casper.start(host);

    casper.waitFor(
        function () {
            return casper.evaluate(function () {
                return !!window.ENV;
            });
        },
        function () {
            test.pass('index.js run');
        },
        function () {
            test.fail('index.js did not run');
        });

    casper.run(function () {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

On the other hand jQuery gets initialized in either environments, I can run jQuery code in evaluate context well, so this will pass:

```
casper.test.begin('jQuery works', 1, function suite(test) {
    casper.start(host);

    casper.waitFor(
        function () {
            return casper.evaluate(function () {
                try {
                    return !!$('html').length;
                }
                catch (e) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        },
        function () {
            test.pass('jQuery works');
        },
        function () {
            test.fail('jQuery did not init');
        });

    casper.run(function () {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

If I log out page events I can see that index.js loads with HTTP result of 200, it just doesn't get executed.

Did someone experienced this before? Does PhantomJS or SlimeJS have some platform specific limitations of script size/complexity?

Comment: Which PhantomJS and Slimer.js version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Yeah, I went through this. There is no error message whatsoever. CasperJS is at 1.1 beta, PhnatomJS is at 2.0, and SlimerJS is at 0.9.6. However I've tried it with casperjs@master but no luck.

Comment: PhantomJS 2.0.0 is known to hide some errors. Why don't you try it with 1.9.8?

Comment: You're right, the error was hidden away by PhantomJS 2.0. I get "Error: SyntaxError: Parse error" with 1.9.2. So, there should be some hidden ES6 dependent code in my compiled JS file definitely. That should be the reason of failing test cases on OSX, because its [XUL build is younger than Windows one](https://slimerjs.org/download.html). Thanks man, you helped me a lot!